# Using WHERE clause with LIKE and OR

Tags: mysql, search, where-clause

I have this sql statement for my search function.

```
$a_search = "$a%";
$sql = "SELECT a.*, u.*
        FROM articles AS a
        LEFT JOIN users AS u
        ON a.written_by = u.username
        WHERE a.written_by OR a.title LIKE ? // want to search for both
        ORDER BY a.written_by ASC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$a_search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
// more code ...
```

Works fine except one thing. It searches the articles ONLY where the `a.title` match. But I also want to search by the author and that's why I added `a.written_by`. However it still only searches for the `a.title`. So my question is how can I search for **both** at the same time?

Comment: `WHERE a.written_by like ? OR a.title LIKE ?` with a second bind_param... Or `CONCAT(a.written_by, a.title) like ?` which may or may not work for your needs.

Comment: The first one worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote has no condition on a.written_by
you have to do something like

```
$a_search = "$a%";
$sql = "SELECT a.*, u.*
        FROM articles AS a
        LEFT JOIN users AS u
        ON a.written_by = u.username
        WHERE a.written_by LIKE ? OR a.title LIKE ? // want to search for both
        ORDER BY a.written_by ASC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($a_search,$a_search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
// more code ...
```

This will send the result **where a.written_by LIKE $a_search or a.title LIKE $a_search**

Answer (score 0):

you cannot give a common or and....gotta mention it in each case...for e.g.

```
$a_search = "$a%";
$sql = "SELECT a.*, u.*
        FROM articles AS a
        LEFT JOIN users AS u
        ON a.written_by = u.username
        WHERE a.written_by ='cat' OR a.title LIKE 'dog' ? // want to search 
        ORDER BY a.written_by ASC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$a_search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
// more code ..
```